# If I define method with (arg, ...args), the parameters will reverse

Tags: groovy

for instance:

```
def m(arg, ...args) {
    println "arg: $arg"
    println "args: $args"
}

m('arg', k:'v')
```

output:

```
arg:['k':'v']
args:['arg']
```

I think the right output should be

```
args:['arg']
arg:['k':'v']
```

Answer (score 5):

Groovy has a special ordering rules for map parameters, if they take the first position in the arguments list

```
def fn(Map params, ...args) {
    println "params = $params and args = $args"
}
```

Then, calling the method with:

```
fn(1, 2, 3, something:'else')
```

Will print:

```
params = [something:else] and args = [1, 2, 3]
```

Groovy also has special ordering rules for Closure parameters, in that if they are the last parameter:

```
def fn2(a, b, Closure cl) {
    cl(a, b)
}
```

Then you can place them outside the parentheses when calling the method, ie:

```
println fn2(1, 2) { a, b -> a + b } // prints 3
```

Because you have omitted types on all your parameters, it's just sticking the map as the first parameter